Bootstrap popover does not show
I am trying to use a BS popover, my first time. I need to use the same popover for multiple elements so content and title will be dynamic. I googled and viewed a bunch of suggestions and still can't get this to work. I can see when element (a Fontawsome icon) is clicked, the appropriate function is called to fetch the title and content, but having problems with the popover.
<label>
  Some Text
  <span>
    <i
      class='fas fa-question-circle descPopover'
      aria-hidden='true'
      data-bs-toggle='popover'
      data-bs-placement='top'
      data-bs-trigger="focus"
      data-html="true"
      data-content="<div id='descContainer'>Loading...</div>"
      title="Click for more info"
      onclick="showDescr('vpc')"
    ></i>
  </span>
</label>

<label>
  Some Other Text
  <span>
    <i
      class='fas fa-question-circle descPopover'
      aria-hidden='true'
      data-bs-toggle='popover'
      data-bs-placement='top'
      data-bs-trigger="focus"
      data-html="true"
      data-content="<div id='descContainer'>Loading...</div>"
      title="Click for more info"
      onclick="showDescr('vpc')"
    ></i>
  </span>
</label>

function showDescr(code) {
    var descr = 'some description fecthed from an array';
    var heading = 'some title fecthed from an array';
    $('.descPopover').data("title", heading);
    $('.descPopover').data("content", descr);
    $('.descPopover').popover('show');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]').popover();  
        
    $('.descPopover').on('show.bs.popover', function (e) {
        var popover = $(this);
        var content = popover.data('content');
        var title = popover.data('title');
        $('#descContainer').html(content);
    });
    // ...
});

When the question mark icon is clicked, it shows a popover, with two titles, presumably one for each label, one above the other, ("Click for more info") and the text "Loading ..." and no way to close it.
I put a breakpoing on showDesc() and can see it gets called but on('show.bs.popover') doesn't.

Even though it's not quite clear, what your final goal is, here's a simple setup that will make both popovers work with the dynamic content:
<label>
  Some Text
  <span>
    <i
      class='fas fa-question-circle descPopover'
      tabindex="0"
      aria-hidden='true'
      data-bs-toggle='popover'
      data-bs-placement='top'
      data-bs-trigger="focus"
      data-html="true"
      data-content="<div id='descContainer'>Loading...</div>"
      title="Click for more info"
      onclick="showDescr('vpc', this)"
    ></i>
  </span>
</label>

<label>
  Some Other Text
  <span>
    <i
      class='fas fa-question-circle descPopover'
      tabindex="0"
      aria-hidden='true'
      data-bs-toggle='popover'
      data-bs-placement='top'
      data-bs-trigger="focus"
      data-html="true"
      data-content="<div id='descContainer'>Loading...</div>"
      title="Click for more info"
      onclick="showDescr('vpc', this)"
    ></i>
  </span>
</label>

  function showDescr(code, el) {
    var descr = 'some description fecthed from an array';
    var heading = 'some title fecthed from an array';
    $(el).attr("data-bs-title", heading);
    $(el).attr("data-bs-content", descr);
    $(el).popover('toggle');
  }
  $("[data-bs-trigger='focus']").on("blur", e =>{
    $(e.target).popover("hide");
  })



function showDescr(code, el) {
    var descr = 'some description fecthed from an array ' + Math.random().toFixed(2);
    var heading = 'some title fecthed from an array '  + Math.random().toFixed(2);
    $(el).attr("data-bs-title", heading);
    $(el).attr("data-bs-content", descr);
    $(el).popover('toggle');
  }
 $("[data-bs-trigger='focus']").on("blur", e =>{
    $(e.target).popover("hide");
  })
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.7.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-5Hs3dF2AEPkpNAR7UiOHba+lRSJNeM2ECkwxUIxC1Q/FLycGTbNapWXB4tP889k5T5Ju8fs4b1P5z/iB4nMfSQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<label>
  Some Text
  <span>
    <i
      class='fas fa-question-circle descPopover'
      tabindex="0"
      aria-hidden='true'
      data-bs-toggle='popover'
      data-bs-placement='top'
      data-bs-trigger="focus"
      data-html="true"
      data-content="<div id='descContainer'>Loading...</div>"
      title="Click for more info"
      onclick="showDescr('vpc', this)"
    ></i>
  </span>
</label>

<label>
  Some Other Text
  <span>
    <i
      class='fas fa-question-circle descPopover'
      tabindex="0"
      aria-hidden='true'
      data-bs-toggle='popover'
      data-bs-placement='top'
      data-bs-trigger="focus"
      data-html="true"
      data-content="<div id='descContainer'>Loading...</div>"
      title="Click for more info"
      onclick="showDescr('vpc', this)"
    ></i>
  </span>
</label>



As you see, I am passing a second argument to the onclick handler, so that for each element, the handler has access to the element that triggered the call.
showDescr('vpc') => showDescr('vpc', this)
I have also switched to $().attr to make this work, along with switching over to toggle instead of show so that the handler automatically hides/shows the element. Otherwise, you'll get a flickering issue, when the code tries to show an already open popover.
I've also included a working demo. Open and try the snippet.
Update: in order for the popover to toggle on 'blur' (while the user clicks on another part of the DOM), I've added a required tabindex on the 2 elements and an onblur handler to hide the popovers.

Thank you. I thought when you set trigger to 'focus' then clicking anywhere would dismiss the popover. However, as shown in your example, one has to click on question icon again to dismiss it.

@NoBullMan I've updated the code and it now works.
